# How to properly reload Marmalade Quick simulator?

Tags: macos, marmalade, marmalade-quick

I'm moving to Marmalade Quick and I've got something that irritates me incredibly.

In theory, hitting Ctrl+R should reload the simulator, loading all lua files again. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Lua callstack:QUICKCPP LOG: Reloading Quick main.lua file...
QUICKCPP ERROR: [string "main.lua"]:11: loop or previous error loading module 'dhMain
```

soo... does this mean I have to restart the simulator every time I make a code change, instead of just reloading the files?
It takes very long for simulator to restart, btw.

Comment: which version of Marmalade is that? 
[8.5 release notes](http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/Release+Notes#Releasenotes-8.5ReleaseNotes) have this very suspicious note "MSDK-3075 Fixed an issue where pressing 'T' or 'R' would restart Quick applications. Corrected bindings are Ctrl+T and Ctrl+R."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to reload the simulator is by pressing Ctrl+T on both, windows and osx platforms.

Comment: ^T and ^R do different things, don't remember exactly - one restarts the simulator, the other restarts only Quick subsystem or some such